# Switching existing project from Android-5.0-Lollipop to Android-6.0-Marshmallow

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am switching my existing project from Lollipop to Marshmallow. And in project i am using Google Map, few services, GCM and few other things. So please tell me what are the necessary things that i should keep in mind before switching? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done so yet, but one thing I know is You have to take permissions at runtime. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.